# well-ordered vs. perfectly ordered

Tags: set-theory

A well-ordered set of numbers fulfills two conditions (Georg Cantor):

1. The set has a very first element.
2. Every element of the set that has successors (Q) has an immediate successor.

For example, the set of natural numbers, 0,1,2,3…, is well-ordered. Another rather weird looking but well-ordered set is the following: arrange all even numbers in ascending order and then append all odd numbers in descending order: 0,2,4,6,…..,5,3,2,1.
Condition 2 is satisfied because if the number Q is even, the immediate successor is Q+2; if Q is odd, the immediate successor is Q-2.

A perfectly ordered set, on the other hand, must fulfill a third condition (Cesare Burali-Forti):

3. Any element M either has no immediate predecessor or it has a predecessor P (let me call it an achor) that itself has no predecessor, such that there are fintely many elements between M and P.

Take, for example, the set of all even numbers arranged in ascending order and then append all odd numbers, also in ascending order: 0,2,4,6,…..,1,3,5… Condition 2 is satisfied (whatever the number Q, its successor is Q+2).

Let’s show that Condition 3 is satisfied. First note that both 0 and 1 have no immediate predecessors; they will be our anchors. If M is even, then the predecessor 0 serves as P, if it is odd, the predecessor 1 serves as the anchor. There are always finitely many numbers between the anchor and M. Hence,

0,2,4,6,…..,5,3,1 is well-ordered but not perfectly ordered.
0,2,4,6,…..,1,3,5,… is both well-ordered and perfectly ordered.

BUT THIS IS WRONG!
Because every well-ordered set is perfectly ordered but not conversely.
So where is my mistake?

Comment: Irving M. Copi: "The Burlai-Forti Paradox"

Comment: ??? [Burali-Forti paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox): "demonstrates that constructing "the set of all ordinal numbers" leads to a contradiction".

Comment: according to Cantor's two conditions, a well-ordered set does not need to be transitive

Comment: Can you provide references for where these definitions are taken from?

Comment: Copi:  Examples are easily constructed of
 sets that are perfectly ordered but not well-or-
 dered, as, e.g., omega(1 + *omega). On the other hand, it
 is easily proved that every well-ordered set is
 perfectly ordered. <<< It seems to me that 'perfectly ordered' -- with three conditions -- must be more restrictive than 'well-ordered' with only two conditions. But apparently, it is the other way around??

Comment: Are you under the impression that conditions 1 and 2 constitute the definition of a well-ordered set? Where did you get that idea? Is that in some book or what?

Comment: definitions are for example in: The Burali-Forti Paradox
Author(s): Irving M. Copi
Source: Philosophy of Science , Oct., 1958, Vol. 25, No. 4 (Oct., 1958), pp. 281-286

Comment: @bof: It seems from the paper by Copi, which explains the confusion of Burali-Forti with the definitions. I'm not sure where the OP gets the rest.

Comment: or in Wikipedia "Well  Order": Another well ordering of the natural numbers is given by defining that all even numbers are less than all odd numbers, and the usual ordering applies within the evens and the odds:

0 2 4 6 8 ... 1 3 5 7 9 ...
This is a well-ordered set of order type ω + ω. Every element has a successor (there is no largest element). Two elements lack a predecessor: 0 and 1.

Comment: See also Jean van Heijenoort (editor) [From Frege to Gödel  :A Source Book in Mathematical Logic (Harvard UP, 1967), page 104](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA104): "Burali-Forti's paper contains an erroneous conception of well-ordered set".

Comment: the error was in Burali-Forte's first paper (feb 1897). He corrected it in a paper he published in november 1897

Comment: $0,2,4,6,\ldots,5,3,1$ doesn't strike me as well-ordered.

Comment: Angina: why not? it fulfills the two conditions of a well-ordering. (Note that transitivity is not needed for a well-ordering)

Comment: @georges In modern math usage, a well ordering is one which is linear (hence transitive) and has no infinite descending sequence. So “evens in order followed by odds backwards” is not a well ordering by the common usage, while “evens followed by odds (both forward order)” is a well ordering. Without a common definition, this will be a confusing discussion, to put it mildly.

Comment: @george: As we all keep repeating, the paper is about Burali-Forti's **mistake**. You are trying to hold up his mistake as if it was the right definition, and we are trying to explain that it is not. A set is well-ordered if it is a partially ordered set and every non-empty subset has a minimum (this implies linearity which is sometimes taken as a part of the definition). By definition well-orders are transitive.